# Pruning a tree by mapping nodes of tree that fail a test to its children

Tags: javascript, algorithm

My problem here builds upon [another problem I was trying to solve and received an excellent answer for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090371/create-a-pruned-copy-of-tree-in-javascript) where I have a tree:

```
const treeData = [{
  title: '0-0',
  key: '0-0',
  children: [{
    title: '0-0-0',
    key: '0-0-0',
    children: [
      { title: '0-0-0-0', key: '0-0-0-0', children: [] },
      { title: '0-0-0-1', key: '0-0-0-1', children: [] },
      { title: '0-0-0-2', key: '0-0-0-2', children: [] },
    ],
  }, {
    title: '0-0-1',
    key: '0-0-1',
    children: [
      { title: '0-0-1-0', key: '0-0-1-0', children: [] },
      { title: '0-0-1-1', key: '0-0-1-1', children: [] },
      { title: '0-0-1-2', key: '0-0-1-2', children: [] },
    ],
  }, {
    title: '0-0-2',
    key: '0-0-2',
    children: []
  }],
}, {
  title: '0-1',
  key: '0-1',
  children: [
    { title: '0-1-0-0', key: '0-1-0-0', children: [] },
    { title: '0-1-0-1', key: '0-1-0-1', children: [] },
    { title: '0-1-0-2', key: '0-1-0-2', children: [] },
  ],
}, {
  title: '0-2',
  key: '0-2',
  children: []
}];
```

and an array of leaf nodes:

```
const leafNodes = ['0-0-1-2', '0-1-0-1', '0-1-0-2']
```

Before, I just wanted a filtered/pruned copy of the tree that contains all the paths to the leaf nodes, but now I would like to further prune it by removing the parent node that doesn't satisfy a test -- the test being having all of its children included in the list of leaf nodes.  The resulting tree would look like this:

```
const pruned = [{
    title: '0-0-1-2',
    key: '0-0-1-2',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: '0-1-0-1',
    key: '0-1-0-1',
    children: []
  }, {
    title: '0-1-0-2',
    key: '0-1-0-2',
    children: []
  }
]
```

Here, the node with keys `0-0-1` would be removed because only one of its 3 child nodes (`0-0-1-2`) is included in the leafNodes list and the child nodes included in the leaf nodes list (in this case, just the one) are bumped up to the level of their now removed parent.  This would flow back up to the parent of the removed node, now with key `0-0`, since not all of *its* children are included in the pruned tree.

This same pattern would apply to `0-1`.

Comment: in case of keeping the parent nodes, what should happen if all of the leaf nodes are select, but the path to them has still branches?

Comment: My assumption is that all nodes being selected/included will result in an exact copy of the source tree.  I'm not sure if that answers your question.  Please let me know if I can provide further details. Thanks again for the previous answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and check if the child are complete selected , then get the actual node or just some children, then take the children only.

```js
function getShort(array, keys) {
    var result = [],
        every = true;

    array.forEach(o => {
        var children;

        if (keys.includes(o.key)) return result.push(o);
        if (!o.children || !o.children.length) return every = false;

        children = getShort(o.children, keys);
        if (children.length && children.length === o.children.length) return result.push(o);

        result.push(...children);
        every = false;
    });

    return every
        ? array
        : result;
}

const
    treeData = [{ key: '0-0', children: [{ key: '0-0-0', children: [{ key: '0-0-0-0', children: [] }, { key: '0-0-0-1', children: [] }, { key: '0-0-0-2', children: [] }] }, { key: '0-0-1', children: [{ key: '0-0-1-0', children: [] }, { key: '0-0-1-1', children: [] }, { key: '0-0-1-2', children: [] }] }, { key: '0-0-2', children: [] }] }, { key: '0-1', children: [{ key: '0-1-0-0', children: [] }, { key: '0-1-0-1', children: [] }, { key: '0-1-0-2', children: [] }] }, { key: '0-2', children: [] }],
    leafNodes = [
        '0-0-0-0', '0-0-0-1', '0-0-0-2', // all 0-0-0 all 0-0
        '0-0-1-0', '0-0-1-1', '0-0-1-2', // all 0-0-1 all 0-0
        '0-0-2',                         // all 0-0-2 all 0-0
        '0-1-0-1', '0-1-0-2'
    ],
    short = getShort(treeData, leafNodes);

console.log(short);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```